# Restify serveStatic and separate function call after

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, restify

I'm trying to serve static files when user enters route '/'.

```
server.get(/\/?.*/, [restify.serveStatic({ directory: 'public/', default: 'index.html'}), exampleFunction])
```

So my goal is to server static files (it works), and after that to run a function called *exampleFunction.*

How can I achieve that? Now only the serveStatic gets called, and I didn't find a way to run exampleFunction right after that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont dont know what frameworks etc you are using but I'll guess...

You can not pass an array to server.get but you can make your own function to

```
server.get(/\/?.*/, function(req, res){
    restify.serveStatic({ directory: 'public/', default: 'index.html'});
    customFunction();
})
```

Comment: I tried that one and restify.serveStatic doesn't work although customFunction gets called.